# Unity loading textures in the background without freezing the game

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, background, coroutine

In my app the user can walk, and that changes the texture on a sphere.
To save on ram I wanted to have dynamic loading, so I calculate the distance between any pair of images and only load those who are close.

I want to do this loading in the background but currently every load is freezing the game.
I have tried loading all of the assetbundles ahead of time and only loading the assets in runtime - still freezes. (The freezing is on Android BTW, not on the comp)

For my code I use an array of [RemoteFiles](https://github.com/gszauer/Unity-PartialDownload/blob/master/Assets/RemoteFile.cs), a class made for loading assetbundles. Each AssetBundle has one texture in it.

My code is currently like this:

```
IEnumerator loadTextures(){

    //Load assetbundles - texts is the array of textures
    for (int j = 0; j < texts.Length; j++) {
        yield return StartCoroutine (PicManager.Instance.remoteFiles[j].LoadLocalBundle ());
    }

    //dynamic loading
    while (true) {

        int index = Picture the user is currently on;

        for (int j = 0; j < texts.Length; j++) {

            //if transitions[i,j] is true, the images are close enough and and j needs to be downloaded
            if (transitions [index, j]) {

                //if the texture is not loaded, load it
                if (texts [j] == null) {

                    AssetBundleRequest request = null;
                    request = PicManager.Instance.remoteFiles [j].LocalBundle.LoadAssetAsync (j + ".jpg", typeof(Texture));
                    yield return request;                           
                    Texture cube = request.asset as Texture;
                    PicManager.Instance.texts [j] = cube;
                    //PicManager.Instance.remoteFiles [j].UnloadLocalBundle ();
                }

            } else {

                //if the texture is loaded, unload it
                if (texts [j] != null) {
                    Resources.UnloadAsset (texts [j]);
                    texts [j] = null;
                }

            }
        }


        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.05f);

    }
}
```

Am I doing something wrong, or is loading textures in the background not possible?

Thank You!

Comment: (1) "To save on ram..." Why?  It's incredibly unlikely you'll ever run low on memory.  (2) Unity is exceptionally bad at loading things in background - it is only good at it with audio files. It's one of the few real engineering problems with Unity.

Comment: The textures are very large, I I don't do it dynamically it costs over a gig on ram and crashes

Comment: ok; it seems strange that only a couple GB of textures would crash any modern device.  but sure ... anyway, the answers are (a) check out www class (b) check out the "new" LoadResourceAsync call (which is hopeless) and (c) unfortunately this is basically a "known limitation" in Unity.  (It's worth noting that, even if you want to do this as a native programmer, it is incredibly difficult.)

Comment: Thank you Joe,  basically the class I'm using has www inside, and the assetbundles are already loaded, so the problem is loading the texture into the resources. I will check out that function,hope it works, thank you!

Comment: no problem but "the class I'm using has www inside" looks like you have not included that code in your question. That would be the critical aspect.

Comment: Thanks, I have included a like to the git i took the code form, but i should have stated that

Comment: oh I see you're using something that's out there. Look it's entirely possible that is defunct, it is two years old so probably doesn't work on the face of it.  i notice it mentions "for iOS", there is (should be) no difference in Unity how it runs on different platforms.  I'm sorry, for me I don't have time to look at the class, cheers

Comment: i would just use some simple "www" code (it's like 2 lines of code), search on here for some answers!

Comment: Hey Joe, nothing worked for me so I just abandoned the idea